OAuth Scope Error in Gmail API for Sending Emails with Google OAuth in Python
I'm integrating Google OAuth to send emails on behalf of users. My function for sending emails throws the following error:
('invalid_scope: Bad Request', {'error': 'invalid_scope', 'error_description': 'Bad Request'})
The scopes in my code include:

SCOPES = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
    'openid'
]


In the send_email function, I load credentials from credentials.json and attempt to send the email with service.users().messages().send. Here is the core function:


def send_email(self, userToEmail, messageText):
    try:
        service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=self.load_credentials())
        message = MIMEText(messageText)
        message['to'] = userToEmail
        message['subject'] = 'Test Email'
        encoded_message = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_bytes()).decode()
        result = service.users().messages().send(userId="me", body={'raw': encoded_message}).execute()
        return f"Message sent: {result['id']}"
    except Exception as error:
        print("Error:", error)
        return f"Error occurred: {error}"



I've confirmed that my OAuth consent screen includes these scopes. Any insights on why the invalid_scope error persists would be appreciated!
